# create data frame of interactions between two factors

Tags: r

I have two 2x2 data frames.  Each column in each data frame is a factor.

I want to create a 2x8 data frame that contains each factor and the interactions between factors.

Here is an example:

```
df1 <- data.frame(V1 = factor(c('a', 'b')), V2 = factor(c('c', 'd')))
df2 <- data.frame(V3 = factor(c('e', 'f')), V4 = factor(c('g', 'h')))
df.combined <- combine(df1, df2)
```

Where `df.combined` would be

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V1:V3 V1:V4 V2:V3 V2:V4
 a  c  e  g   a:e   a:g   c:e   c:g
 b  c  f  h   b:f   b:h   d:f   d:h
```

(I don't want the V1:V2 or V3:V4 interactions.  Not needing those interactions is just in the nature of the problem that I face.)

Is there a succinct way to get `df.combined` in R?

Comment: why not V1:V2 and V3:V4 as well?

Comment: @Chase -- That's just the peculiar task that I have.  It requires interactions between columns in different data frames, but not between columns in the same data frame.  I edited my post to say so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the colons in the name are not required, it is just one line of code that takes care of both column binding the two data frames and creating the interactions.  Using your two data frames:

```
df.combined <- with(c(df1, df2), data.frame(df1, df2, V1:V3, V1:V4, V2:V3, V2:V4))
```

which gives

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V1.V3 V1.V4 V2.V3 V2.V4
1  a  c  e  g   a:e   a:g   c:e   c:g
2  b  d  f  h   b:f   b:h   d:f   d:h
```

If you need the colons in the names, another oneliner will change periods to colons:

```
colnames(df.combined) <- gsub("\\.", ":", colnames(df.combined))
```

leaving the final results

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V1:V3 V1:V4 V2:V3 V2:V4
1  a  c  e  g   a:e   a:g   c:e   c:g
2  b  d  f  h   b:f   b:h   d:f   d:h
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not usre it this meet your definition of "succintly".

```
dfc <- cbind(df1,df2)
dfc2<- cbind( dfc, `V1:V3`=interaction(dfc$V1, dfc$V3, sep=":"), 
                   `V1:V4`=interaction(dfc$V1,dfc$V4, sep=":") )
df.combined <- cbind( dfc2, `V2:V3`=interaction(dfc$V2, dfc$V3, sep=":"), 
                            `V2:V4`=interaction(dfc$V2,dfc$V4, sep=":") )
> df.combined
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V1:V3 V1:V4 V2:V3 V2:V4
1  a  c  e  g   a:e   a:g   c:e   c:g
2  b  d  f  h   b:f   b:h   d:f   d:h
```

(It is generally not recommended to have colons in variable names. They will then always need to be quoted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. Maybe not terribly elegant or succinct, but possibly useful...

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c("a", "b"),
                  V2=c("c", "d"),
                  V3=c("e", "f"), 
                  V4=c("g", "h"))

factor_pairs <- expand.grid(c("V1", "V2"), 
                            c("V3", "V4"),
                            stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

for (i in 1:nrow(factor_pairs)) {
    factor_1 <- factor_pairs[i, 1]
    factor_2 <- factor_pairs[i, 2]
    new_col_name <- paste(factor_1, factor_2, sep=":")
    dat[[new_col_name]] <- paste(dat[[factor_1]], dat[[factor_2]], sep=":")
}

dat
#   V1 V2 V3 V4 V1:V3 V2:V3 V1:V4 V2:V4
# 1  a  c  e  g   a:e   c:e   a:g   c:g
# 2  b  d  f  h   b:f   d:f   b:h   d:h
```